# JavaFX TableView not triggering selection callbacks

Tags: java, events, javafx, tableview

I'm having an issue with JavaFX TableView not triggering the selection callbacks. I set these two callbacks:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item selection changed.");
});
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(observable -> {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item index changed.");
});
```

There's one thing that I found confusing. Selection changed events are only triggered on the first selection and on starting a multi-selection. Index changed seem to happen on every change. Why is that?

My big problem however is that when I select multiple entries and then select the last one I clicked on, thus, undoing the multi-selection but not changing the item in focus, no event is triggered. Hopefully this will make it clear:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? How can I know when the selection changed like that?

My minimum example is four files:

Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Record.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Record {
    private SimpleStringProperty c1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty c2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Record(String c1, String c2) {
        this.c1.setValue(c1);
        this.c2.setValue(c2);
    }

    public String getC1() {
        return c1.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty c1Property() {
        return c1;
    }

    public void setC1(String c1) {
        this.c1.set(c1);
    }

    public String getC2() {
        return c2.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty c2Property() {
        return c2;
    }

    public void setC2(String c2) {
        this.c2.set(c2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Record{c1=%s, c2=%s}", c1, c2);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Controller {
    private ObservableList<Record> records = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Record> tableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Record, String> c1Column;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Record, String> c2Column;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        records.add(new Record("c1 - 1", "c2 - 1"));
        records.add(new Record("c1 - 2", "c2 - 2"));
        records.add(new Record("c1 - 3", "c2 - 3"));
        records.add(new Record("c1 - 4", "c2 - 4"));
        records.add(new Record("c1 - 5", "c2 - 5"));

        tableView.setItems(records);
        c1Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("c1"));
        c2Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("c2"));

        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item selection changed.");
        });
        tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(observable -> {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item index changed.");
        });
    }
}
```

and sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="c1Column" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="c2Column" prefWidth="75.0" text="C2"/>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `InvalidationListener`s. These listeners are fired any time an observable value becomes *invalid*: that is, the last computed value may not be up to date.

JavaFX properties can be lazily evaluated. If they become invalid, then invalidation listeners are notified, but their new value is not necessarily computed. If values on which they depend change again before they are recomputed, then they are already invalid, and so invalidation listeners are not notified again. If they are recomputed in the intervening time, then they will become valid upon recomputation, and the invalidation listener will be notified again.

This mechanism is designed for performance reasons: you can imagine, e.g. the layout of a large pane depending on the size and position of many items inside it; but you don't want to recalculate it on every single change: you just need to know when it needs recalculation (when it is invalid).

From your code, it looks as though the way this works is that the `selectedItem` declares a dependency on the `selectedIndex`. When the user selects something, the `selectedIndex` is set directly (invalidating it and changing it), which causes the `selectedItem` to become invalid. However, the `selectedItem` is not explicitly changed until it is recomputed.

You can see all this if you actually recompute the values in the listener:

```
    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item selection changed: "+tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });
    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item index changed: " + tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    });
```

Typical usage would be to register `ChangeListener`s with these properties, instead of `InvalidationListener`s. `ChangeListener`s notify the previous and new values of the property, so they force recomputation of the value anyway:

```
    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item selection changed: "+ oldItem + " -> " + newItem);
    });
    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldIndex, newInde) -> {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " Item index changed: " + oldIndex + " -> " + newIndex);
    });
```

Finally, note that for multiple selection, the [`selectedItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) and [`selectedIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedIndexProperty) properties only reference the last selection. It is possible to change the *list* of selected items without changing the last selection. In this case, the properties won't change at all, so neither change listeners nor invalidation listeners will be notified. For this reason, for multiple selection it is more natural to use a listener on the list of items (or indices) than on the item or index itself:

```
    tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener((Change<? extends Record> c) -> {
            System.out.println("Selected items: "+tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    });
```

(or similarly with `tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener((Change<? extends Number> c) ...);`).

See the [Javadocs for `Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html) and [`ObservableValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html) for more information on the difference between `InvalidationListener` and `ChangeListener`.

Comment: Thank you @James_D. The last bit really helped as the behavior I was describing as the most problematic was happening with both types of listeners on the `selectedItemProperty()`.

Comment: @Pablo The `selectedItem` and `selectedIndex` properties only refer to the last selected item: so in some circumstances you can change the list of selected items without changing the last selection: in this case those two properties won't change (and so no listeners will be fired on them). I'll add a comment to that effect to the answer.